# How do make jquery code executed within order

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('form').submit(function(e) {
                    if (!$('.text').val()) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        console.log('error');
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="text" class="text" value="" />
            <input type="submit" value="Send" />
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('form').submit(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'send.php',
                    type: 'post',
                    success: function() {
                        console.log('done');
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have insert to javascript into the `<head>` and the end of `<body>`.

---

The problem I have is that when I click on the submit button, seems browser executing both my code at the same time.

I don't want combining the both code into one, I just want to execute the javascript code on `<head>`, the stopped if an error occurred, otherwise it would execute the code in `<body>`.

If you just take a look at my problem and share a bit of your science, I'd be very grateful. Thanks!

Comment: The one in the body will always happen first in this case because it gets bound first, just FYI.

Comment: To stop all future event handlers for the current event, you'll want to stopImmediatePropagation as well as preventDefault.

Comment: Why don't you combine both script?

Comment: just asking for problems having 2 submit handlers

Comment: I'm implementing small project, which I was not allowed to interfere in other people's javascript, I can only write code in `head` tag of the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JQuery will execute the event handlers in the order they are bound, but as @KevinB has pointed out in a comment, the one in the `<body>` is bound first because that code is executed as it is encountered, while the one in the `<head>` is bound second because it is executed during the page-ready event.

You could rearrange the code so the two handlers are bound in the correct order and then use `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` in the first handler when you want to prevent the second from executing, but it would be better to bind just a single handler.

Just place one `<script>` block in the `<head >` and bind one submit handler.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('form').submit(function(e) {
            if (!$('.text').val()) {
                e.preventDefault();
                console.log('error');
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'send.php',
                    type: 'post',
                    success: function() {
                        console.log('done');
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, I insert code into the top of the `body` tag, not include `$(document).ready()`... my problem was resolved!

Answer (score 0):

when you use

> .submit( handler )

you bind a event handler actually you are binding two handlers.

if you only want to send the form after a validation
you can validate and then a simple

> .submit()

which is different according with jQuery documentation
https://api.jquery.com/submit/